# Android - How to get KeyEvent KeyCode to Char?

Tags: android

I want to get the char value of the KeyCode Event when pressing an Android keyboard.

Example :

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode,  android.view.KeyEvent event) {
    //InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

//  Toast.makeText(this, "KEYVALUE"+String.valueOf(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));

    return onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Note** : I got value number but i did not get value character.

Comment: A quick search on google would have given you the answer and would have been faster than posting your question on SO

Comment: Hi kimimsc what are the tried below i mention.

Comment: // first option
int unicode = event.getUnicodeChar();
// second option with meta-state
int unicode = event.getUnicodeChar(event.getMetaState());
// third option over the KeyCharacterMap
KeyCharacterMap map = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.BUILT_IN_KEYBOARD);
int unicode = map.get(keyCode, event.getMetaState());

// once you have the unicode as integer you can do this to get the char
char unicodeChar = Character.toChars(unicode)[0];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char unicodeChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
```

Comment: Hi kimimsc i am using latest version in my mobile lollipop 5.0.i didn't get char.

Comment: Hi kimimsc see this link: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/9296/getunicodechar-in-android-mode

Comment: I only can read numeric chars. When I press the other characters nothing happens, it is as if the keyboard not connected to event, and the data

Comment: Hmm..I see. So what you are saying is that the `onKeyUp` method isn't called when you press non numerical keys ?

Comment: okay wait, i'll do some tests. Is it like a custom editText field or the basic one ?

Comment: Thank you kimimsc .But i won't get char value from any field .i want to get from keyboard only.

Comment: Yeah i got that ;). Just another question: you are using a soft keyboard right (the one displayed in the phone when you press an editable field) ?
Could you post more code ? Like the part when you setup the listener ...

Comment: just created EditText field Kimimsc.used keyboard view.But my requirement if i want to typing character .i want to get from keyboard.not from EditText field Thanks

Comment: Kisimsc ya i am used soft keyboard.mobile MOTO G Thanks

Comment: Okay, so you cannot/should not use the `KeyListener` for soft keyboard (as per their [guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html)) as of JellyBean if I'm not mistaken. To be honest I hadn't used it for a long time. I am working on another way to achieve what you want. Will let you know when it works